# iTunes Music stops when I open my application

Tags: ios, background, mobile-safari, itunes, avaudiosession

I am using AVAudioSession and I am activating in my browser on launch. I have set category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback. I have not set any category options. I want audio to be played even in background. If I don't use AVAudioSession then I will not able to play audio even in background. I don't want my app's audio to mix up with iTunes song and play both simultaneously. As its browser application, we don't need audioSession always but when playing audio alone. Similar to how mobile Safari handles audio when iTunes music is on. I saw other category options and modes of AVAudioSession. Kindly give any suggestions for the same.

Comment: have you added Set Required background mode to App plays audio in info.plist

Comment: yes it is perfectly working in background. My problem is that, the iTunes music stops when I open my app.

Comment: where do you set your audio session? just where you need it, or at launch?

Comment: on launch. i don't exactly know how to add where I need. I should find if a particular URL is playing audio. Any idea in how to find it?

Comment: I thought of checking MIME-TYPE of response and depending on that activating session. Don't know if that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Here I fixed this,

**Xcode 10.x**  **Swift 4**

Add the following code in your **AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return true
}
```

**Note: -** Please configure options as required. E.g to stop a background audio while a video file being played add

```
 options: [.allowAirPlay, .defaultToSpeaker]
```

And don't forget to enable audio and airplay in Background mode
[image]